# How I can every 24 hours automatically send all data from Firebase to an email address and all database will be erased?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have an iOS and Android Apps that store data in one of these databases: Firestore or Firebase. I've not decided each one I will be using, depends if I'll find the solution.
I want to store in database data just for one day, each day send all data to email and erase all the database.
And this scenario I need to do every day.

Answer (score 0):

They're both easy to do. To give you an idea with Firestore, it's easy enough to read a series of documents and delete them.

You could run a task that runs every night looking for any document with a timestamp > 24 hours ago. Read all the documents in, then using the document references you get from the read, go ahead and just run a delete on them. Should be relatively painless to set up.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give a direction? Do I need JS code or I can just use the configuration on Forestore webpage or I can do it treough my ios app?